# Sum of column is not working in join table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sum, left-join, union

I am trying to calculate the `req_qty` and `in_qty` from `table1` and `table2`.
I am trying to fetch the joined 3 tables data `SUM(req_qty)`, `SUM(in_qty)`. Issue come if `req.qty` not save in `table2` it will not works. I am left joining the table by this `sku's ids`

I made here a very simple table for calculating the sum of the column. generally, the sum of the column is multiplying the total rows.
Please don't close the post and guild for other thread. for my doubt clear i made here a table which I can understand. please help.

```
table1

ID  |  sku_1 | req_qty | trans_id
----------------------------------
1   |  123   | 150     | 12345
2   |  142   | 200     | 256314
3   |  123   | 100     | 896523
```

table2

```
ID  | sku_2  | in_qty  | trans_key
-----------------------------------
1   | 142    | 50      | 002563
```

table3

```
ID |  sku_code  |  sku_name
--------------------------
1  | 142        |  ABC
2  | 123        |  XYZ
```

Expected Output

```
ID | sku | sku_name | reqQty | inQty 
------------------------------------
1  | 123 | XYZ      | 250    | 0        
2  | 142 | ABC      | 200    | 50
```

Comment: Can you please share the query and perhaps even create a fiddle? Recommended reading: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and [tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question).

Comment: I tried my best to elaborate on the question. even I tried to make the table. I have experience on StackOverflow when I share the link of fiddle nobody opens and marks it as closed, duplicate, how to improve tags? and on hold. I don't know why peoples hate me

Comment: Nobody hates you. We have no reason to have anything personal against you. We judge by the question. Your question won't be closed just because it has a fiddle, it might be closed if it *only* has the fiddle (the code to create the schema needs to be included in the question), if it was unclear or perhaps a fitting duplicate is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit to select data when table1 and table2 are empty**

```
SELECT table1.id, table3.sku_code as sku, table3.sku_name, 
       sum(table1.req_qty) as reqQty, sum(table2.in_qty) as inQty
  FROM table3
  LEFT JOIN table1 on table3.sku_code = table1.sku_1
  LEFT JOIN table2 on table3.sku_code = table2.sku_2
  GROUP BY table1.id, table3.sku_code, table3.sku_name
```

**Explanation**

You can see an explanation on how left join works here [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp#:~:text=The%20LEFT%20JOIN%20keyword%20returns,if%20there%20is%20no%20match](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp#:%7E:text=The%20LEFT%20JOIN%20keyword%20returns,if%20there%20is%20no%20match).

But to explain this query quickly, we will select all data from table3, left join will find all records from left table (here table3) and mathcing records from right tables (here table2 and table 1).

Comment: suppose if `table1` and `tale2` is empty how I fetch `table3` data in your code

Comment: is your code will do sum if table2 will fill ?

Comment: See my edit for sum, I think you need to read some documentation on how to write sql query